# How does one integrate this equation?

Tags: integration

Can somebody put me on the right track regarding how to integrate the following equation?

$$a x +b+c \frac{dx}{dy}=0$$

I am stuck at this stage:

$$ \frac{a}{c}+\frac{b}{c x}+\frac{1}{x}\frac{dx}{dy}=0$$

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Math.SE.  Thank you for your question.  We will be better able to help you if you provide the context of where this problem comes from.

Comment: @vadim123 This equation comes from analysing an electronic circuit consisting of an inductor, a resistor and a diode. Alex Jordan's answer put me on the right track to solving it. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write it as $$c\frac{dx}{dy}=-(b+ax)$$ and then divide by what is in parentheses to separate variables.

Comment: Thanks, I feel quite stupid now. ;-)

Comment: My previous comment was stupid for sure, sorry.